# QT C++ remove file with * (name contains)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

If I have some files in dir `test.txt, test2.txt, test3.txt`, I can remove all of them by using cmd command

`del test*.txt`

How to do the same with `QT C++` without using `system()`

I've tried

`QFile("test*.txt").remove();`

but it is not working.

Comment: You need to use something from Qt that actually supports wildcards.  A quick search finds [this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-dialogs-findfiles-example.html) showing how to iterate a directory using wildcards.

Comment: this uses `QDirIterator`, i know this but i need thing smaller to do as i explained

Comment: Well it's strange that you accepted the answer that uses `QDirIterator`, even though you knew about it already.  That was the point of the example, to show how to iterate through a directory using a wildcard.  The *only* difference is that you want to remove the file that's found in the wild card search, not just display the name.

Comment: I'm looking for the smallest code so i used `QDir` because `QDirIterator` needs to set variable (can not put it in the same `foreach` loop), thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main task is to filter the files so we can use `QDir` with the `nameFilter` as shown below:

```
QDir dir("/path/of/directory", {"test*.txt"});
for(const QString & filename: dir.entryList()){
    dir.remove(filename);
}
```

Or use QDirIterator:

```
QDirIterator it("/path/of/directory", {"test*.txt"});

while (it.hasNext())
    QFile(it.next()).remove();
    //QDir().remove(it.next());
```

Comment: thanks i created a function from these codes to make it easier